# How to train LSTM on multiple inputs?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

Team I'm trying to classify LSTM on donors choose dataset with multiple inputs, But 
I'm getting the following error
TypeError: len is not well defined for symbolic Tensors. (sub_4:0) Please call `x.shape` rather than `len(x)` for shape information.
The is code for my architecture as below

```
# Create model
# tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
keras.backend.clear_session()
input1 = Input(shape=(pad_essay.shape[1],),name="essay_input")
embedding_layer_text = Embedding(vocab_size_text,300, weights=[embedding_matrix],input_length=max_length_text,trainable=False)(input1)
lstm1 = LSTM(300,activation='relu',return_sequences=True,kernel_constraint=keras.initializers.he_normal(seed=0))(embedding_layer_text)
flatten1 = Flatten()(lstm1)

input2 = Input(shape=(1,),name = "school_state")
embedding_layer_school_state = Embedding(unique_school_state-1,20,input_length=1)(input2)
flatten2 = Flatten()(embedding_layer_school_state)

input3 = Input(shape=(1,),name ="project_grade_category")
embedding_layer_grade = Embedding(unique_project_grade_category-1,20,input_length=1)(input3)
flatten3 = Flatten()(embedding_layer_grade)

input4 = Input(shape=(1,),name='categories')
embedding_layer_categories = Embedding(unique_project_subject_categories-1,10,input_length=1)(input4)
flatten4 = Flatten()(embedding_layer_categories)

input5 = Input(shape=(1,),name='sub_categories')
embedding_layer_sub_categories = Embedding(unique_project_subject_subcategories-1,30,input_length=1)(input5)
flatten5 = Flatten()(embedding_layer_sub_categories)

input6 = Input(shape=(1,),name = 'teacher_prefix')
embedding_layer_teacher_prefix = Embedding(unique_teacher_prefix,10,input_length=1)(input6)
flatten6 = Flatten()(embedding_layer_teacher_prefix)

input7 = Input(shape=(numerical_df.shape[1],1),name ='other_numerical_input')
dense1 = Dense(64,activation='relu',kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.he_normal(seed=0))(input7)
flatten7 = Flatten()(dense1)

concate_layer = concatenate(inputs=[flatten1,flatten2,flatten3,flatten4,flatten5,flatten6,flatten7],name="concat",axis=-1)

dense_layer1_after_concat = Dense(128,activation='relu',kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.he_normal(seed=0))(concate_layer)
drop_out1_after_concat = Dropout(0.3)(dense_layer1_after_concat)
dense_layer2_after_concat = Dense(64,activation='relu',kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.he_normal(seed=0))(drop_out1_after_concat)
drop_out2_after_concat = Dropout(0.3)(dense_layer2_after_concat)
dense_layer3_after_concat = Dense(32,activation="relu",kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.he_normal(seed=0))(drop_out2_after_concat)
output_layer = Dense(units=1,activation='sigmoid',kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.glorot_uniform(seed=0),name="output")(dense_layer3_after_concat)

first_model = Model(inputs = [input1,input2,input3,input4,input5,input6,input7],outputs=output_layer)
opt = Adam(lr=1e-3, decay=1e-3 / 200)
first_model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
# first_model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer=opt,metrics=["accuracy"])

first_model.fit([pad_essay,X_train_school_state_le,X_train_project_grade_category_le,X_train_project_subject_categories_le,X_train_project_project_subject_subcategories_le,X_train_teacher_prefix_le,numerical_df1],y_train,validation_data=([pad_essay_test,X_test_school_state_le,X_test_project_grade_category_le,X_test_project_subject_categories_le,X_test_project_subject_subcategories_le,X_test_teacher_prefix_le,numerical_df_test1],y_test),epochs=10,batch_size=64,callbacks=[roc])
```

I have done custom encoding for categorical variable
and use predefined model(word2vec) for text data

The sample custom encoding as below

```
le = LabelEncoder()
unique_school_state = len(X_train['school_state'].unique())+1
X_train_school_state_le = le.fit_transform(X_train['school_state'].values)
le_dict_school_state = dict(zip(le.classes_, le.transform(le.classes_)))
X_test_school_state_le= X_test['school_state'].apply(lambda x: le_dict_school_state.get(x,unique_school_state))
```

Comment: So, what's the problem to use `x.shape`?

Comment: @Yoskutik, I can't understand what are saying.

Comment: In which line are you getting the error? is it when you define `unique_school_state`?

Comment: When I'm calling model.fit I'm getting error